# Python, comparing identical strings return False

Tags: python, string, comparison

I'm aware that many questions of the kind were posted here, but I couldn't find one that matches my case.

I have a list made up of dictionaries, where each dictionary contains only a single key, and a list as its value. For example: `keyList = [{'key1': [1,2,3]}, {'key2': [3, 4, 5]}, ...]`

Now, I want to create a simple function which receives two arguments: an aforementioned list, and a key, and returns a matching dictionary from a given list.

the function is:

```
def foo(someKey, someList):
    for i in someList:
        if str(i.keys()).lower() == str(someKey).lower():
            return i
```

When called: `foo('key1', keyList)`, the function returned the None object (instead of `{'key1': [1,2,3]}`.

The two compared values have the the same length and are of the same type (`<type 'str'>`), yet a comparison yields a False value.

Thanks for advance for any assistance or/and suggestions as to the nature of the problem.

Comment: Do you really need to do case-insensitive comparison?

Answer (score 2):

`dict.keys()` returns a list in Python 2 and view object in Python 3, so you're comparing their string representation with the string you passed here. Instead of that you can use the `in` operator to check if the dictionary contains the key `someKey`, as you want to do a case insensitive search you'll have to apply `str.lower` to each key first:

```
def foo(someKey, someList):
    for i in someList:
        if someKey.lower() in (k.lower() for k in i):
            return i
```

Also if your dicts always contains a single key then you can get the key name using `iter()` and `next()`:

```
>>> d = {'key1': [1,2,3]}
>>> next(iter(d))
'key1'
```

So, `foo` will be:

```
def foo(someKey, someList):
    for i in someList:
        if someKey.lower() == next(iter(i)).lower():
            return i
```